# Wallet password with special unicode character

Tags: password

I created a new wallet address with a password containing a unicode special character like � (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER).
See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

The wallet could be created in Ethereum Wallet / Mist and the password confirmation dialogue apparently worked out as well.

Now when I am trying to send some ether to another wallet, the password dialogue tells me that the password is wrong. Are there any known issues with unicode characters in passwords, or do I need to "escape" / mask those characters in a special way?

Means for example: the character � with "\uFFFD" or Alt +FFFD
see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm

Any help / hint is greatly appreciated

Cheers
Stefan

Comment: I'm not sure the wallet can handle unicode strings properly. I'd stick to ascii just to be safe